# seq or time stamp for publishing a message

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am currently working on a web interface to control a turtlebot and i am using [ROSLIBJS](http://robotwebtools.org/tools.html) but i am not too sure what to put for seq and time stamp for the /MoveBaseActionGoal message. If I put a number, it will work for the first time but it i want the turtlebot to go to another destination after it reached its first goal, it will not work because the time stamp is supposed to be the ROS time now.
However, I don't know how to get ros time now on ROSLIBJS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284741/seq-or-time-stamp-for-publishing-a-message/) by [Ashecotton](https://answers.ros.org/users/33434/ashecotton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-07**:
As far as I can recall the `seq` field should be set for you and you should use ROS time to set the time stamp. I can't look up the documentation for this which is why I'm posting this as a comment.

**Comment by [Ashecotton](https://answers.ros.org/users/33434/ashecotton/) on 2018-03-07**:
Yeah me too, I understand that I need ros time for the time stamp but I just don’t know how to get it in the JavaScript or ROSLIBJS. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at [the implementation of the `SimpleActionServer`](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs/blob/45792e1d90ac2c201513dc9f1f508d24c7da6b0c/src/actionlib/SimpleActionServer.js#L138), you'll see that you can use the `Date` object to get the time (in milliseconds):

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var secs = Math.floor(currentTime.getTime()/1000);
var nsecs = Math.round(1000000000*(currentTime.getTime()/1000-secs));
that.statusMessage.header.stamp.secs = secs;
that.statusMessage.header.stamp.nsecs = nsecs;
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0